# NSNotification: possible to receive when Controller doesn't exist yet?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

If I'm using `NSNotifications` to tell my `UITableViews` (in different Controllers) to add a new Cell, but the Controller in which that `UITableView` lies has not been "accessed" yet or loaded/init'd, that Controller will not receive the message (as my `NSNotificationCenter` is setup in each of my `viewDidLoad`). This is the expected behavior as I understand.

Now my question: Is there a way to have the Controller's that haven't been accessed yet once the app launches receive the notification? Or is there a better approach of posting to another `UIViewController`'s `UITableView` from a different `UIView` rather than using `NSNotifications`?

I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481236/problems-with-nsnotifications-not-working-on-view-controllers-that-have-not-be) asked a few years back, so if anyone can chime in, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: More common way is controlling the data set before initialising the UITableView. You can keep a flag in a singleton class for data set changes and if there is a change you can load the new items.

Comment: or you could use -awakeFromNib to setup notifications, as it is guaranteed all view controllers are initialized. Do note,
-(void) awakeFromNib is only called if your object is loaded from XIB.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your controller to receive a notification before it's accessed (i.e. its view is loaded and `viewDidLoad` is called) then you need to subscribe for a notification in one of the `init` methods:

1. If you want to create your controller programmatically then you need to do it in `init` or `initWithStyle:` methods.
2. If you want to create your controller programmatically from `.xib` file then you need to do it in `initWithNibName:bundle:` method.
3. If you want to create your controller from `.storyboard` file then you need to do it in `initWithCoder:` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lebyrt! `initWithCoder` made my controller hang with the view staying black, but `awakeFromNib` seemed to do the trick as @lead_the_zeppelin suggested!